# What is the use of Data Model while API Parsing in swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, model, alamofire

Why we should use Data model while parsing API. whereas we can simply get response in the ViewController class it self.

Can someone tell me why we should use Data Model to parse api response..

Thanks in advance

Comment: easy to use and more complex code divide into separate.

Comment: Maintaining arrays is very conflict process to perform operation on json data, data model reduces difficulty of processing local data.

One important benefit is if you are going to use local database like sqlite then data model is very useful to parse data to database...Once you use data model definitely you will understand what I mean.

Comment: Ok It is easy to use.but we have declare too many variable to handle a single API response.? @SagarBhut

Comment: And What if I don't have to use any local Database for that particular API.? @teja_D

Comment: Playing with arrays instead of data model is not better option, this is my opinion...if you want to use array go with.. ty @Maruf

Comment: That's my only concern that why playing with array instead of data model is not a better option??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine that you have below json response from server after calling an API:

```
{
"settings": {
    "isUserActive": false,
    "isUserAdmin": false,
    "rollNumber": 10,
    "userId": 2,
    "userName": "John"
},
"status": 200,
"message": "Success"
}
```

Now how will you access the value if you are not using data model. It will be like

```
let name = response["settings"]["userName"]
```

(Assuming that you have converted the json into dictionary)

1) What if you have to use the username at multiple place, then you have to do the same thing again.

2) The above json response is simple so it will be easy to get a particular value, but imagine a json where there are nested objects, trying to retrieve a value manually can be pain.

3) If you are working in a team there is a probability that some developers can misspell the key and it can take hours to debug.

Using data model the compiler will throw error if the property is misspelled avoiding bugs.

4) You will have to typecast every time you retrieve the data from dictionary.

When using data models, need to do typecasting only once ie. when parsing the json.

All this pain can be avoided simply using data model, you only have to parse the json once and you can simply use the key as property to access value.

For example see the settings json, once you parse it to data model it can be used like this:

```
let data = dataModel(json: jsonResponse)
data.settings.userName // John
data.settings.rollNumber //10
data.status //200
```

This is a good tool to convert the json in to data models [Link](https://github.com/insanoid/SwiftyJSONAccelerator)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Suppose My Json response is nested of course, but I only have to use the json response at one time only. So In that case, is this still a good approach to use Data Model. or I can simply hard code to my specific class.??

Comment: Like I said its about ease of use, clean code and avoiding bugs. It totally depends on how you want to use it. response.keyname1.keyname2.keyname3 is far better than response["keyname1"]["keyname2"]["keyname3"]